# Setting Blank lines to ON before executing a SQLFILE in shell script

Tags: scripting, sqlplus

```
echo exit | sqlplus username/password@host_ip:port/Service_name @SQLFILENAME
```

I want  to execute `set sqlbl on` before executing The `SQLFILENAME` and also want that after executing `SQLFILENAME` it should exit sqlplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$SQLPLUS -S username/password@ip:port/servicename<< EOF
SQL-STATEMENTS
set sqlbl on 
commit
EOF
```